# JavaScript: onmouseout event not working after onmouseover

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write code for a ToolTip, where when the mouse goes over it the text shows, and when it moves away it goes away. I'm trying to do it by changing classes (`tipHide` in css has `display:none`, and `tipShow` has `display: block`), but the `onmouseout` event doesn't change the class back (which I know from seeing the generated source after).

How can I fix it so the `onmouseout` event will trigger if the `onmouseover` event already has changed the class.

My HTML:

```
<div id="zha" class="cfield">
    <p id="qmark"></p>
    <p id="toolTip" class="tipHide">Text Shown</p>
</div>
```

and JavaScript:

```
function toolTip() {           
    document.getElementById('qmark').onmouseover = function() {
        var toolTip = document.getElementById('toolTip');
        toolTip.className = 'tipShow';
    }
    document.getElementById('qmark').onmouseout = function() {
        var toolTip = document.getElementById('toolTip');
        toolTip.classname = 'tipHide';
    }
}
```

**Also I'd like to do it without using JQuery**

Comment: Apart from the typo, the function name might conflict with the `id` of the `p` element (in the case `tooltip` function is global).

Comment: Ok, thank you I'll fix that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a typo on the [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property? In your `onmouseout` you got this:

```
toolTip.classname = 'tipHide';
```

Which should be(the same you did on `onmouseover`):

```
toolTip.className = 'tipHide';
             ^
```

Comment: Damn, you're right. I was so busy looking for the difficult answer I missed the obvious

Comment: @cfleming93 its fine, it happens all the time.